# Expose L2TP network inside OpenVPN

Tags: routing, windows-server-2012-r2, openvpn, rras, l2tp

I have a L2TP permanent connection setup in RRAS within Windows Server 2012R2 and an OpenVPN service listening for inbound connections. I'd like that the OpenVPN clients to have access to the network exposed by the L2TP VPN.

I've tried setting up a route inside the OpenVPN to route the traffic for the L2TP network but the packets stop when the reach the OpenVPN host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the L2TP interface in RRAS -> IPv4 -> NAT to get it working.